# simplifying tidyeval with multiple symbols

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

The following function behaves as desired: several variables can be passed to `group_by` without the need to put them into `alist()` or `dplyr::vars`:

```r
mean_by_grp <- function(df, meanvar, grp) {
  
  grouping <- enexpr(grp) %>% 
    expr_deparse %>% 
    str_split(",",simplify = T) %>% `[`(1,) %>% 
    map(str_remove,"c\\(") %>% map(str_remove,"\\)") %>% map(str_trim) %>% 
    unlist %>% syms
  
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!!syms(grouping)) %>% 
    summarise("average_{{meanvar}}" := mean({{meanvar}}, na.rm = TRUE),
              .groups = 'drop')
}

starwars %>% mean_by_grp(height, species)
starwars %>% mean_by_grp(height, c(species, homeworld))
```

However, it is complicated. I need to turn c(var1,....varn) into a string, split it and turn it into a list of symbols so I can use with with `syms`.

Isn't there a much easier way to do this?

Of course, I could use ellipses instead of grp, but then I can only have one argument that passes multiple symbols to another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be `dplyr::across`:

```r
mean_by_grp <- function(df, meanvar, grp) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(across({{ grp }})) %>% 
    summarise("average_{{meanvar}}" := mean({{meanvar}}, na.rm = TRUE),
              .groups = 'drop')
}

library(dplyr)

starwars %>% mean_by_grp(height, species)
#> # A tibble: 38 × 2
#>    species   average_height
#>    <chr>              <dbl>
#>  1 Aleena               79 
#>  2 Besalisk            198 
#>  3 Cerean              198 
#>  4 Chagrian            196 
#>  5 Clawdite            168 
#>  6 Droid               131.
#>  7 Dug                 112 
#>  8 Ewok                 88 
#>  9 Geonosian           183 
#> 10 Gungan              209.
#> # … with 28 more rows
starwars %>% mean_by_grp(height, c(species, homeworld))
#> # A tibble: 58 × 3
#>    species  homeworld   average_height
#>    <chr>    <chr>                <dbl>
#>  1 Aleena   Aleen Minor             79
#>  2 Besalisk Ojom                   198
#>  3 Cerean   Cerea                  198
#>  4 Chagrian Champala               196
#>  5 Clawdite Zolan                  168
#>  6 Droid    Naboo                   96
#>  7 Droid    Tatooine               132
#>  8 Droid    <NA>                   148
#>  9 Dug      Malastare              112
#> 10 Ewok     Endor                   88
#> # … with 48 more rows
```

Comment: Correct. Just one question: why does `group_by` not work directly with curly-curly, but `across` does ... and so does `select`?

Comment: Hm. Good Question. Unfortunately I have no convincing answer on that. According to the [Progamming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) vignette there are two forms of dplyr verbs, the one that use data making and the ones that use tidy select. `group_by` falls to the first group, while `select` falls into the second. And for the first group we have to make use of `across`.

Comment: That makes sense! Though it wasn't clear to me from the argument description. But now for the icing on the cake: If I want to sort by average_{{meanvar}}, how to do it shorter than `arrange(!!sym(glue::glue('average_',expr_deparse(enexpr(meanvar)))))`?

Comment: Haha. :D Try with `arrange(across(paste0("average_", as_name(enquo(meanvar)))))`. That#s the best I can come up with.

Comment: Or with `glue::glue` instead of `paste0` and `enexpr` instead of `enquo` for that fancier look ;-) Thanks! `as_name` is the key tool here.

Comment: Regarding your first question, you will find the answer in this vignette: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html

Comment: Also look into using `.data` when you have a name as a string, e.g. `my_name <- paste0("average_", as_label(enquo(meanvar))); df %>% arrange(.data[[my_name]])`.

In the next version of rlang coming out this week you'll also be able to use the new `englue()` function to make this easier: `my_name <- englue("average_{{ meanvar }}")`

Comment: @LionelHenry. Thanks for sharing. `englue` sounds and looks like a great option.